# How to make a html random redirect

Tags: javascript, html

How I would go about making a website that randomly redirects between multiple (in this case 2) websites?

Obviously what is below doesn't work due to what I hope is the meta tag; I would like to know if the javascript code is the correct way to do this
 and how it would work.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://example1.com">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if Math.random() =< 0.5;
          window.location.href = "http://example1.com/"
        else;
          window.location.href = "http://example2.com"
    </script>
    <title>Page Redirection</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your javascript syntax inside script tag is not correct either

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if ( Math.random() <= 0.5 ) //proper parenthesis surrounding the condition and also < will come before =
          window.location.href = "http://example1.com/"; 
        else //semicolon removed from here
          window.location.href = "http://example2.com";
    </script>
```

Comment: Remove `;` after else

Comment: @Rajesh looked like I overlooked more things I should have :)

Comment: Sorry, weird python habits and general stupidity, im guessing I remove the
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://example1.com">

Comment: @Zeludon Meta tag won't be required anymore. Meta tag was not doing the refresh conditionally anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You did it right (almost), Wrap the condition in `()` and remove `;`, it will break the `if`.

```
if (Math.random() =< 0.5)
    window.location.href = "http://example1.com/";
else
    window.location.href = "http://example2.com";
```

**Keep in mind one little fact.**

```
if(false)
   alert(1);
```

Won't `alert` anyting as the `if` condition is always false. But if you see

```
if(false); // If will break here.
   alert(1);
```

Will always alert as if breaks and then the execution proceeds without if.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the function a little bit more generic:

```
  var sites = [
                        'http://www.dilbert.com',
                        'http://stackoverflow.com',
                        'http://Starwars.com'
                      ];
   var target = Math.floor(Math.random() sites.length);
    window.location = sites[target];
```

So when your site collection grows you don't need to alter the code. You could even pack it into a function:

```
       function goRandomSite(sites) {
             var target = Math.floor(Math.random() sites.length);
             window.location = sites[target];
              }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Oh wow, Thanks, I've been trying to figure out how to do something like this.